# c# - How to get reference to object A inside A's class?

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my SharePoint 2010 c# / asp.net site, I have a class defined like

```
namespace PDF_Library.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class PDF_Library : Usercontrol   
    {
         public static PDF_Library current;
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
         {
              current = (PDF_Library)this; 
         }
    }
}


public static class Page_State
{
    public static Page is_display()
    {
        return PDF_Library.current.Page; // didn't work...
    }
}
```

It doesn't have a constructor. 
How can I get the reference to `the current instance of this class`?

I tried something like this in the top

`public static PDF_Library current;`

Then in a function it had

`current = (PDF_Library)this;`

But that didn't work...

Comment: Reference to the class or to the instance?

Comment: current instance of the class

Comment: Then what is wrong with `this`?

Comment: if you mean what I tried above, that didn't work.

Comment: ok I updated the question, there is a second class where I try to access the first class's Page variable.

Comment: @omega You need to include how you are assigning the value `current`

Comment: ok I again updated the code above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to understand that it does not work this way. Your question is tagged with asp.net - multi-user, multi-threaded environment where multiple instances of `PDF_Library` user control will be created all the time. It is absolutely uncertain which one of them will be hanging off `PDF_Library.current`. You need to rethink your design.

More on this: `Page` instance is disposed of when the request processing is finished. Normally this instance with all its controls and things such as `Response`, `Request`, `Context` etc will be set for garbage collection. Because you keep a reference to a `UserControl` instance in a static field, all these objects (including `Page`) will be kept in memory until this `current` reference is replaced with something else.

Comment: so its best if I don't have any static variables in that PDF_Library class right?

Comment: This is too sweeping a statement. .NET allows static variables and they exist for a reason. Just don't assign references to objects that are meant to be short-lived to static fields.

Answer (score 3):

It is the fact that you used `static` in the function that was assinging `current` that `this` did not work. `static` is a method that is not tied to any instance of the class, therefor you can not use `this`.

Your only options are either make the method non-static or pass in a instance of the class as a parameter to the static function.

From what I can tell you are trying to create a "[Singleton Pattern](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx)". See the link to the previous MSDN article for examples on how to create a singleton class.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it will have an instance. If the class is marked as static (which it doesn't appear to be) then you can just reference it by name "PDF_Library". Other wise, use ILSpy or reflector to look at the end result. I bet it has a constructor; just because you don't see one, doesn't mean it isn't there. Override the default ctor and set your instance there.

```
namespace PDF_Library.VisualWebPart1
{
    public partial class PDF_Library : Usercontrol   
    {
        public static PDF_Library Current;
        public PDF_Library() : base() {
           Current = this;
        }

    }
}
```

The problem you might be having with your Page_Load code is that it's being called too late in the lifecycle and that's why your reference call isn't working.

Comment: this worked, but I think I can't write my code like this because of Igor's response above.